# a4j: ajax event="change" doesn't work on the first click, but on the second click

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have a form using JSF with rich faces. In the form there are two radio buttons: "Yes" and "No". The default selection is "Yes". When clicked "No" a text area should appear below. But it doesn't. Instead It appears in the second click; I first click "No" (Default was "Yes") nothing happens and then I click "Yes", now it works, the text area below appears but it automatically chooses "No".

Here is the code:

```
<h:outputLabel for="cheapest">Cheapest Flight?</h:outputLabel>
                <h:selectOneRadio id="cheapest" value="#{myController.selectedItem.cheapest}" disabled="#{myController.showMode}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{yesNoTypeItems.items}" />
                    <a4j:ajax event="change" render="@form" execute="@form" />
                </h:selectOneRadio>

                <h:outputLabel for="newArea" rendered="#{myController.selectedItem.cheapest == false}">New Text Area</h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputTextarea id="newArea" rendered="#{myController.selectedItem.cheapest  == false}" disabled="#{myController.showMode}"
                    value="#{myController.selectedItem.newArea}" style="width:300px;height:100px;">
                </h:inputTextarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

> onchange - Javascript code executed when this element loses focus and its value has been modified since gaining focus. ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneRadio.html))

Perhaps unfortunately named the change event doesn't fire when you expect it to. Use the click event and check if the value is actually being changed if you need to.